# QGIS – Edits to shapefile attribute table won't save special characters

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table

I'm working in QGIS with a Government of Canada shapefile of all 338 federal electoral districts.

The encoding is UTF-8.

In the attribute table, all of the *em dashes* ("—") that should appear in the riding names have been replaced by question marks.

I've used the field calculator to replace the question marks with the proper em dashes, but those changes won't save properly. If I close and re-open the attribute table, the question marks re-appear.

But if I replace the question marks with non-special characters (e.g. "AAA"), there doesn't seem to be an issue. So the problem seems to be tied to the em dash.

Any ideas on what might be going on?

Comment: The dBase-III format predates UTF, so shapefiles are always going to have difficulty with non-ASCII codepoints. If you convert to a codepage-safe format, the data just might work.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you! Is there a particular format you would recommend?

Comment: File geodatabase utilizes UTF-16, so it wouldn't get tangled up, but just about every other format in creation, including CSV, is more UTF-resilient than shapefile.